# Populating column in pandas dataframe using a function call

Tags: python, pandas

How can I use `.loc` with `.str.match()` to update column values but with a function call? The code I'm trying is like;

```
df.loc[df['Col1'].str.match(r'\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d', na=False), 'Col2'] = _my_func(df['Col1'])
```

a simple regex pattern to find date format, and then `_myfunc()`;

```
def _my_func(data)
    for row in data.iteritems():
        day = int(row[1][:2])
        month = int(row[1][3:5])
        year = int(row[1][6:])
        fecha = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0)
        diff =  fecha - datetime.datetime.now()
        if diff.days > 0:
            return 'Yes'
        elif diff.days < 0:
            return 'No'
```

Is this a correct way to return values from the function into the dataframe?

Also if I insert a `print('test')` into the `_my_func` just before either `return`, it only prints `test` one time, instead of a print for each row in the data passed to the function, does anyone know why? Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at `pandas.DataFrame.apply` ?

Comment: Your function takes a `pd.Series` but returns *just one* yes or no answer. This would be why your print test only occurs once. For this to work using this method (i.e. instead of using `df['Col1'].apply(_my_func)`) you'd need to maintain all the 'yes' and 'no' results into an iterable (list or pd.Series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment:

```
def _my_func(x):
    day = int(x[:2])
    month = int(x[3:5])
    year = int(x[6:])
    fecha = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0)
    diff = fecha - datetime.datetime.now()
    if diff.days > 0:
        return 'Yes'
    elif diff.days < 0:
        return 'No'
```

Followed by:

```
df.loc[df['Col1'].str.match(r'\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d', na=False), 'Col2'] = df['Col1'].apply(_my_func)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I edited out the first index in your answer because it wasn't needed after making the apply changes, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try it using `apply()` function.

For example:

`df['loc1'] = df['loc1'].apply(_my_func)`

Then it would take each row of the dataframe and pass it as input to the function `_my_func`.